# Unfortunately the app has been stopped which is downloaded from play store

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

First i would like to request people for don't make this to duplicate because i have posted this query after so much work on my issue.
I am new to google play store and have published my new application(prepared from cordova) in play store.Initially it was publishing properly and after downloading also it was working fine.
Later, I have published my app with the new keystore and new package then it has been published successfully but not able to open in device. It is giving the following error.
"Unfortunately the app has been stopped." I don't know what happened suddenly. I tried many trouble shooting techniques but they did not help me. Initially i thought
it is problem with device but i tried in 3 different devices but it does not work.

Especially the play store is taking so much time to publish even after fixing the issues.
Could any body please tell me what might be the reason for the above error?

Comment: its Crashing after download or its just not able to download fully?

Comment: I have tried in 3 devices but still it gave the same error.

Comment: does your app downloading properly from Play Store?

Comment: yes it is downloading properly.

Comment: It is not a problem with the device right it is wasting lot of my time, please tell me if we can debug this app from play store.

Comment: I had the same problem.

Comment: Clean your project and rebuild its working fine for me.

Comment: It is working fine locally, i am getting this error when download it from play store.

Comment: I had a same problem, and issue was: I had not clean + build before creating apk. So please try cleaning + building, then create apk, and publish.

Comment: Thank you @MysticMagic, actually i have many unpublished apps on my  play store account, So after building the project i need to change the package name in manifest.xml, then i can not build it again because it will reset the package name.

Comment: You need to edit the old published app with new apk. means new version number and version code, not a new package.

Comment: yes i know that but initially my keystore has been corrupted, that's why i started to upload as a new app

Comment: Ok, then you've gotta publish a new app. Good luck. just keep in mind that you clean build before creating apk :)

Comment: yes that's right. thats why i am changing package name and publishing a new app and it causes the problem. after changing the pkg name i am not building it. is it okay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61729/discussion-between-mysticmagic-and-m-s-naidu).

Answer (score 0):

As app is getting properly downloaded from PlayStore so it may be the problem or error in side your application.

We can not debug our application from PlayStore but you can use ACRA *[Source Code](https://code.google.com/p/acra/)* to get ErrorLogs at your email address.

For Example code please follow this link.

- [Acra-application-crash-report-android](http://www.helloandroid.com/content/acra-application-crash-report-android)